# Filter out a specific LogCat message from a library

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

A library I'm using (com.jaredrummler.android.device.DeviceName) is printing the below stack trace repeatedly. I'd like to make it stop but can't figure out how. How can I get rid of this message but keep all others in my LogCat?

````
2021-10-07 22:37:37.292 19816-19912/com.simplifieditproducts.ubchromebook W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for manufacturer
2021-10-07 22:37:37.292 19816-19912/com.simplifieditproducts.ubchromebook W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:392)
2021-10-07 22:37:37.292 19816-19912/com.simplifieditproducts.ubchromebook W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:553)
2021-10-07 22:37:37.292 19816-19912/com.simplifieditproducts.ubchromebook W/System.err:     at com.jaredrummler.android.device.DeviceName$DeviceInfo.<init>(DeviceName.java:374)
2021-10-07 22:37:37.292 19816-19912/com.simplifieditproducts.ubchromebook W/System.err:     at com.jaredrummler.android.device.DeviceName$DeviceInfo.<init>(DeviceName.java:347)
2021-10-07 22:37:37.292 19816-19912/com.simplifieditproducts.ubchromebook W/System.err:     at com.jaredrummler.android.device.DeviceName.getDeviceInfo(DeviceName.java:186)
2021-10-07 22:37:37.292 19816-19912/com.simplifieditproducts.ubchromebook W/System.err:     at com.jaredrummler.android.device.DeviceName.getDeviceName(DeviceName.java:138)
2021-10-07 22:37:37.292 19816-19912/com.simplifieditproducts.ubchromebook W/System.err:     at com.jaredrummler.android.device.DeviceName.getDeviceName(DeviceName.java:111)
2021-10-07 22:37:37.292 19816-19912/com.simplifieditproducts.ubchromebook W/System.err:     at com.simplifieditproducts.picturekeeperlibrary.drive.PKC_FileSystem.copyAssetToUsbDrive(PKC_FileSystem.kt:72)
2021-10-07 22:37:37.292 19816-19912/com.simplifieditproducts.ubchromebook W/System.err:     at com.simplifieditproducts.picturekeeperlibrary.main.backup.models.BackupCopier$startBackup$1.invokeSuspend(BackupCopier.kt:170)
2021-10-07 22:37:37.292 19816-19912/com.simplifieditproducts.ubchromebook W/System.err:     at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
2021-10-07 22:37:37.292 19816-19912/com.simplifieditproducts.ubchromebook W/System.err:     at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
2021-10-07 22:37:37.292 19816-19912/com.simplifieditproducts.ubchromebook W/System.err:     at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
2021-10-07 22:37:37.292 19816-19912/com.simplifieditproducts.ubchromebook W/System.err:     at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
2021-10-07 22:37:37.292 19816-19912/com.simplifieditproducts.ubchromebook W/System.err:     at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
2021-10-07 22:37:37.292 19816-19912/com.simplifieditproducts.ubchromebook W/System.err:     at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)```
````

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to collapse these lines, you can follow these steps:

1. Select the TAG text in Logcat, and perform a right-click.
2. In Right Click options, select "Fold Lines Like This". A dialog will appear asking to add the selected text to a list of "Folded Lines".
3. Tap OK and that's it.

[image]

Comment: This is great to know, but I don't think I want to fold all System.err tags. And there's no other text in common that I can use to fold them all without potentially folding messages coming from elsewhere.

Comment: Right. Instead, you can import library's files directly if you're willing. It has only [two java files](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidDeviceNames/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/jaredrummler/android/device) and [one database file in assets](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidDeviceNames/tree/master/library/src/main/assets). Required dependencies are listed [here](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidDeviceNames/blob/master/library/build.gradle) and [here](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidDeviceNames/blob/master/build.gradle). This way you can silent it from within.